# Clickable elements doesn't work after replacement jQuery

Tags: replacewith

I'm trying to replace something identical on a forum with .replaceWith() - it can replace it, but when I press the icons, the text isn't getting added, eventhough the stuff I am replacing is the EXACT same.

What could cause that?

```
$(".class").replaceWith("<table id='table'><img src='smiley.png' class='smiley' /></table>");
```

The code is the exact same, but clicking on the image after replaceWith() has been applied doesn't work. It should add a smiley to the text field, but it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Can you show us your click handler?

Comment: You're probably binding your click event to the element that you're removing.  Try binding the click event to a parent element that won't be removed and filtering for the element you actually want to click on.

Comment: you are not closing the html properly, as you are creating a table and an image insde of it but you are just closing the image.

Comment: Click handler directly from the forum: http://puu.sh/3DOd8.txt @Rayweb_on - it's correct, but it's a long code so it was just a sample.

Comment: hmmm. Just add it to the question  pls

Comment: @ponysmith Thanks, replaceWith returns the replaced content, your sugestion was the one i used. Because im using a jquery object element instead of a selector this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event that filters down from parent to child like this:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function(){
    // your code here
});
```

This will allow for the click event to fire even if a new instance of `.child` is added dynamically.